# Why is UpdateServicereference adding HTTP endpoints, when i only specify net.tcp

Tags: .net, wcf

One of my services has started to add extra HTTP endpoints when I right click on if and select UpdateServiceReference. This causes a run time error saying i have duplicate end points and must specify one by name. I am manually deleting the endpoints for now, but I would like to stop this. I only want the TCP endpoints.

here is the service, below are the "extra" endpoints

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmail" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpConfig" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880"
          maxBufferSize="1048576" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="NotificationBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NotificationBehavior" name="PGFContracts.LiveContractsService.LiveTargetPriceAgreementService">
        <endpoint address="LivePricing" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpConfig"
          name="TCPLivePricing" contract="PGFContracts.LiveTargetPriceAgreementService.ILivePricing" />
        <endpoint address="TpaNotification" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpConfig"
          name="TCPTpaNotification" contract="PGFContracts.LiveTargetPriceAgreementService.ITargetPriceAgreementNotification" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8020" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

these are the endpoints I dont want, the net.tcp ones are also generated correctly. Is it an IIS setting on the server?

```
  <endpoint address="http://xxx:8083/LiveTargetPriceAgreement/LiveTargetPriceAgreementService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILivePricing"
    contract="LiveTPAService.ILivePricing" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILivePricing" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx:8083/LiveTargetPriceAgreement/LiveTargetPriceAgreementService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITargetPriceAgreementNotification"
    contract="LiveTPAService.ITargetPriceAgreementNotification"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_ITargetPriceAgreementNotification" />
```

Comment: The service definition in your config has only netTcpEndpoints. But your client config has only basicHttpEndpoints. And the address in the client side endpoints has a completely different address. I doubt if you are pointing to the correct wsdl while generating service reference. Ideally for this service configuration you should get 2 client endpoints for netTcpBinding one for each contract ILivePricing & ITargetPriceAgreementNotification.

Comment: I didn't include the correct endpoints but they are being generated, I exed out the server name in the endpoints (not really sure why) but the different port points to the address i am exposing the wsdl at. This was working fine and then something changed to break it. I agree with your Ideal assessment but i am also getting the extra HTTP endpoints, thats the problem.

Comment: Have you tried removing the service reference and re-adding instead of using UpdateServiceReference?  It might be pointed to an older version running of your service.

Comment: Well that did it, readding the reference. I copied the url, deleted the reference, and readded it with the same url and it is working properly now. Thanks Chris. It seems like blackmagic but whatever works.